# Vertically combine many matrices

Tags: r

I have a design matrix generated by

```
 grp.ids <- as.factor(c(rep(1,8), rep(2,4), rep(3,2)))
 x <- model.matrix(~grp.ids)
```

Now I hope to vertically concatenate the matrix `x` 100 times. If I only want to do it 2 times, then a call to `rbind(x,x)` will work. How to repeat the process 100 times? Or is there any other function available for directly generating such a big design matrix (based on this small matrix block)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `do.call(rbind, replicate(100, x, simplify=FALSE))`